# C++ Проблема с if во внутреннем цикле

Tags: c++

Через считалку в строке выбираются люди в одномерном массиве и заносятся в очередь. До этого всё работало через остаток от целочисленного деления,но для вариативности считалки нужно заменить на if. Но оно, естественно,не работает,т.к. по условию переменная определяется как 0 и оно 5 раз выводит 0 позицию одномерного массива,т.е. 1.

Подскажите,как можно адекватно втулить во внутренний цикл if,чтобы оно работало?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    std::string sch("Эни, бени, рики, таки, Турба, урба, синтибряки, Эус, бэус, краснобэус, Бац!");
    std::cout << "Считалочка: " << sch << endl;
    queue <int> q;
    int n, j, i;
    int people[5];

    people[0] = 1;
    people[1] = 2;
    people[2] = 3;
    people[3] = 4;
    people[4] = 5;
    cout << "Нумерация людей: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d", people[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;

    std::istringstream ss(sch);
    std::string s;


     n = 0, i = -1;
    while (ss >> s) ++n;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j) 
    {
        i += n;
        if (i > 4)
            i = 0; 

        cout << "Выбывший №:" << people[i] << endl; 
        cout << people[i] << endl;
        q.push(people[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Очередь: ";
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        people[i] = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cout << people[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Чтобы посмотреть какой должен быть результат:
Просто заменить весь if на i %= 5;

Comment: Что значит "для вариативности"? Кто мешает заменить `i%=5` на `i%=M`? Ну, а у вас - напишите `while(i > 4) i-=5;` - все равно вся ваша "вариативность" гробится наличием 4 в условии...

Comment: Я про кол-во слов в считалке. Если,к примеру,будет 10 слов,то остаток тут уже не используешь. Я об этом.

Comment: while(i > 4) i-=5; - вы имеете ввиду,вставить это вместо if  в цикл for?

Comment: while(i > 4) i-=5; помогает именно с этим кол-вом слов. Спасибо.
Но если я уберу одно слово из строки,то оно опять показывает только лишь одно значение все 5 раз.

Comment: Просто проблема в том,что после первого прохождения точка отсчета должна сдвигаться на 1 вперед,пока все не будут внесены в очередь.

Comment: Если убрать одно слово,то оно ломается и я не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вообще ерунда - смотрите: номер `i` у вас может выбыть, но он при этом у вас *не выбывает из списка*. Получается ерунда.

Вот, на коленке набросанный вариант (хотя у меня ощущение, что можно и без дека, что есть какая-то формула для вычисления очередного числа... Но времени думать много нет).

```
queue<int> make_queue(unsigned int count, unsigned int n)
{
    queue<int> q;
    deque<int> d(count);
    generate(d.begin(),d.end(),[m = 0] () mutable { return m++; });
    int j = 0;
    while(!d.empty())
    {
        j = (j - 1 + n)%d.size();
        q.push(d[j]);
        d.erase(d.begin()+j);
    }
    return q;
}
```

В очереди - выбранные индексы (как принято в C++, отсчет индексов начинается с 0 :)).

Comment: Так ничего и не должно выбывать из списка. 
Просто меняется число,с которого считалка начинает отсчет и всё.
До того,как было изменено количество слов - все было отлично,но теперь я не понимаю,почему всё сломалось.

Comment: Формулы нет( искать по словам задача Иосифа. Есть ускоренное ДП. Формула только для каждого 2.

Comment: Блин... Вы повторно проходите считалкой по одним и тем же людям, а не выводите их из круга - так понятнее? Попробуйте считалку из 5 слов для 5 людей и посмотрите, что будет. А будет 5 раз один и тот же человек!

Comment: Понятнее. Но я всё еще не понимаю почему конструкция так усложнилась еще и деком.
Разве с while или if проблему нельзя решить?

Или просто объясните,почему если убрать одно слово из считалки код умирает?

Comment: Да упростил я ее деком. Как вы планируете убирать людей?

Comment: Почему при смене количества слов умирает изначально мой код с вашим while?
Это сейчас не понятно.

Comment: Бумажка, ручка и вперед. Вам не повезло подобрать такие параметры задачи, при которых она дала верный ответ при неверном методе решения.